# First Hollywood movie with "flashbacks within flashbacks within flashbacks"?

Tags: film-techniques, first-appearance

In [Super (2010)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_%282010_Indian_film%29), I noticed the weird concept of **flashbacks within flashbacks within flashbacks**.

Which was the **first Hollywood movie** with the same concept?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Wikipedia article on narrative uses of flashbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashback_%28narrative%29):

> An extremely convoluted story may contain **flashbacks within flashbacks within flashbacks**, as in [Six Degrees of Separation (1993)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108149/), [Passage to Marseille (1944)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0037166/), and [The Locket (1946)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038700/). This technique is a hallmark of Kannada movie director Upendra whose futuristic flick Super (2010) is set in 2030 and contains multiple flashbacks ranging from 2010 to 2015 depicting a utopian India.

IMDB flaged also [Enter the void (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1191111/) with this technique. Seems that **only** these movies used this kind of brain teaser. As I found only these titles, i can answer your question saying that [Passage to Marseille (1944)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0037166/) was the first movie using this technique. If you are interested you can give a look to the detailed plot [here (SPOILER)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0037166/synopsis) looking how the flashbacks were actually mixed.